# How to rotate a 3D matrix around a line by a certain degree?

Tags: rotation, matrix-elements

[Physics Ch 67.1 Advanced E&M: Review Vectors (15 of 55) Coordinate Transformation in 3-D: Ex. 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOx-IOc12vk&list=PLX2gX-ftPVXWYLuDrKIF5npNwEDs4-vt6&index=15)

I was watching the following video where the goal was to find the Coordinate Transformation matrix  about the line from the origin point to (1,1,1) the by 120 degrees and the axis swapped , i tried to visualise this as follows if I want to go a full circle around the line that would be 360 degrees whereas 120 degrees is  one third of the way so the axis swap one time  if we rotate by 240, axes will change twice, and if we rotate one more time, the axes will return to their original position ,now my question is would  rotating by 120 degrees around a different line like the line formed  from (0,1,0) to  (2,5,3) result in the axis swapping too and how would the coordinate transformation matrix look like?